# I am getting "signature verification failed"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tor-install

I downloaded Tor some while ago but never really used it. Recently I started it up and got "Signature Verification Failed. You may be under attack or there might just be a network problem. Click start and try the download again."

I'm not under attack and I don't have a network problem. In fact, I tried from two different networks in two different houses.

My computer is a Linux Ubuntu 16.4 LTS. But I am not an expert Linux admin.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/263).

Answer (score 0):

The error is your "signature" that is old, if you use digital signatures, refresh it. It is also a complaint by MS Office that looks for signatures but never installs one. It would have been so simple at Microsoft been awarded the right to issue certificates, but then they could not install many things and the net could have been safe. 
If you are attacked and get this, it is a very hard DDOS - I doubt that. Your net would be very slow and you would complain of insane waiting time. So install a open community certificate, they will often pull down the rest. Search a CA and avoid those that force you into specific products / services.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I don't understand what Microsoft office has antything to do with this. I don't use any Microsoft products on my home computer.


How would I know if I use digital signatures? If so what are the exact steps to refresh it?


What is an open community certificate? What are the steps of installing one on Linux Ubuntu?